# Hash function for classification

Tags: algorithm, hash, classification

Given a known set $A$ of distinct numbers  $0 ~ 2^(n+1)-1$. In binary mode, it is a n-dimensional vector with 0/1 elements. Now for an arbitrary subset $S$ containing $m$ distinct numbers of $A$, is it possible to find a function $f$, such that $f(S)$ becomes $0,1,...,m-1$, while $f(A\S)$ should not fall in $0,1,...,m-1$. The function $f$ should be as simple as possible, a linear one is preferred. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not hw. I'm just curious about the existence of an elegant such function.

Comment: Okay, then what have you tried?

Comment: I'm thinking using bitset to store a number, $f$ should contain flipping, +/- operators.

Comment: Yet another example of a perfectly on-topic question closed without warning or reason by @casperOne.  Casper:  Just because you don't understand a question *(or just because it looks mathy)* doesn't make it off-topic.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Um, no one said it was off topic.  Did you bother to read the close reason?  I'm guessing no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword you're looking for is a [minimal perfect hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function#Minimal_perfect_hash_function), and yes, it's [always possible](http://burtleburtle.net/bob/hash/perfect.html) to construct a minimal perfect hash function for a given **S**.

Comment: And this "answer" is a comment, you might want to flesh this out into something more substantial.